# Where can I find the Black Armor/Collector's Edition/April 2013 armor?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I want to find the armor that the guy is wearing in the Dark Souls 2 cover art, specifically the Collector's Edition. It looks really cool and like an endgame armor. I own Dark Souls 2 (and have beaten it) and working on Scholar of the First Sin. Is it in either one of those?

[Dark Souls 2: Collector's Edition on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00F6YD2AK) (It'll direct you to the Black Armor Edition, make sure to click on the Collector's Edition.)

Or the armor this guy is wearing in the April 2013 Demo:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [Faraam Knight's set](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Faraam+Set). It can be found in Drangleic Castle, in the main hall with the 5 Sentinels. In the room on the far left (facing the golem statues)

[image]

You can fall through the floor here (it collapses as you walk over it), and you will find the set on a corpse.

The set has a C scaling, except for the chest piece which has A scaling, and upgrades to +10 with Titanite Shards, Chunks and Slabs.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is the [Faraam Set](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Faraam+Set):

[image: Faraam Set screenshot]

> #### Location:
>
> Starting from the King's Gate bonfire in Drangleic Castle, make a right and head into the great hall filled with petrified spear men. Kill the ones at the top left corner to expose a room containing a Ruin Sentinel.
> If you walk inside the room with the Ruin Sentinel, a piece of the floor inside the room will collapse under the player, having them fall into a cave including the "Under Castle Drangleic" bonfire. The cave will include a corpse containing the Faraam set.

<sup>Source: http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Faraam+Set</sup>